# Intuition behind stronger version of Whitney embedding theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

While watching [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZcKSoI17r0) on differential geometry, the lecturer mentions (at around 1:20:00) a stronger embedding theorem than the one by Whitney. The stronger version claims that every $d$-dimensional manifold can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2d - a(d)}$, where $a(d)$ is the number of ones in the binary expansion of $d$. Unfortunately, the lecturer doesn’t give any sources, so I really wonder how this (seemingly) completely unrelated notion comes up here. Does this theorem have a name? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: What you've written is true for immersions, not embeddings. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971304).